# How to set .asmx webservice Enabling Cross-Origin using Asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

My webservice code is

```
 [WebMethod]
     public List<test> GetMachineData_List(string prefix, int person_id)
     {
         using (var db = new TestDB())
         {
             List<test> list = db.Fetch<test>("select id,name from machine_data_collection mc where mc.id=@0 and name like '%" + prefix + "%'", person_id);
             return list.ToList();
         }
     }
```

My jquery Ajax call is

```
 $("#textbx").autocomplete(
            {
                source: function (request, response) {
                 $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost:4787/ws/webservice.asmx/GetMachineData_List',
                        data: { prefix: request.term.toString() ,person_id:1},
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            var jsonArray;
                            try {
                                jsonArray = $.parseJSON(data.d); // using jQuery
                            } catch (e) {
                                jsonArray = data.d; // using jQuery

                            }
                            response($.map(jsonArray, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    id: item.id,
                                    value: item.Name

                                };
                            }));

                        },
                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            var msg = XMLHttpRequest.responseJSON.d;
                            if (msg == undefined) {
                                alert( "Something went wrong !!" + errorThrown);
                            } else {
                                alert( "Error"+ msg);
                            }
                        }

                    });
                },
                minLength: 2,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var idControl = this.dataset.bindcontrol;
                    try {
                        alert(ui.item.id);

                    }
                    catch (ex) {
                        alert( "Oops .. Something happend unexpected !! .. Please redo ");
                    }
                }
            }

    );
```

And i enable the  Cross-Origin in web.config code is

```
 <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:21702/" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-AspNet-Version,X-Powered-By,Date,Server,Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Cache-Control,Connection,Content-Length,Content-Type,Host,Origin,Pragma,Referer,User-Agent" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

When change text in textbox error occured.
Error Meaasge from Ajax call is :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:4787/ws/webservice.asmx/GetMachineData_List. Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:21702' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: Check this article-> https://codequirksnrants.wordpress.com/2014/04/18/using-jquery-ajax-to-talk-to-asp-net-asmx-web-services/

Comment: i got same error.@mybirthname

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add below code snippet in `Web.config` file:

```
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
   </webServices>
 </system.web>
 .............
..............
 <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, content-type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" /> 
        **...(add additional add names and values when you need).......**
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

In my case `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200"/>` the base url of webservice consumer app (Angular) is `http://localhost:4200`.

You have to mention your base url in that specific place.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by **mybirthname** [this article solved it for me](https://codequirksnrants.wordpress.com/2014/04/18/using-jquery-ajax-to-talk-to-asp-net-asmx-web-services/)

I was using a combination of older ASMX web service with newer Web API endpoints.

I used a combination of `web.config` to specify CORS:

```
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, content-type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" />
        <remove name="X-Frame-Options"/>
      </customHeaders>
```

And then a handler in `Global.asax` for the OPTIONS preflight:

```
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
```

This is from the above linked article. However, as I'd already defined some of the headers in `web.config` they weren't needed here (resulted in duplicate values).

Answer (score 0):

try using jsonp in your json call.

```
$("#textbx").autocomplete(
        {
            source: function (request, response) {
             $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:4787/ws/webservice.asmx/GetMachineData_List',
                    data: { prefix: request.term.toString() ,person_id:1},
                    dataType: "jsonp",
```