# Allow content origin on .asmx file

Tags: javascript, .net, xml, web-config, asmx

We are making a website that pulls the Price data (using Javascript) from an old version of a WebService, that we don't have access to. We managed to download the .asmx file locally from the Web service, but we still get the error:

"*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Viktor/Downloads/istorija/CeniGoriva.asmx' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https, isolated-app.*"

How do I add the "Allow Cross Origin header" in the .asmx file? We don't have access to the web.config file.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40646824/how-to-set-asmx-webservice-enabling-cross-origin-using-asp-net ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set .asmx webservice Enabling Cross-Origin using Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40646824/how-to-set-asmx-webservice-enabling-cross-origin-using-asp-net)